# Mariadb GTID replication skip errors

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb

I want to use `GTID`'s in replication setup, I have problems with syncing database, and it gives me errors. How do I skip errors with `GTID+Mariadb`?

I saw some articles regarding GTID and Mysql 5.6 and they do it through inserting empty transaction, but for that they use `Retrieved_Gtid_set`, `Executed_Gtid_set` from show slave status – I don't see any such fields in this command output in `Mariadb 10.0.17`.

Answer (score 0):

This still works in MariaDB...

```
stop slave;
set global sql_slave_skip_counter=1;
start slave;
```

Although this won't work when you're performing failover.